# Image URL of SharePoint list

Tags: column, image

I created a **MediaAlbum List** added an existing column called "Page Image".

```
$.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MediaAlbum')/items?$filter=IsActive%20eq%201&$expand=ContentType",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      });
```

The problem here is in the log I am unable to retrieve see the 'Page Image' column details.

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to your query URL to specify what columns you want to retrieve:

```
$select=Page Image
```

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MediaAlbum')/items?$filter=IsActive%20eq%201&$expand=ContentType&$select=Page Image",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      });
```

Comment: 400 Bad response

Answer (score 1):

**$select :**

Use the $select query option to specify which fields to return for a given list, list item, or other SharePoint object represented by an entity set. You can use $select=* to return all available fields.

**In General Case :**

In general, if you do not specify the $select query option, the REST service returns all available fields by default. However, in a few cases, some SharePoint objects include properties that are very resource intensive to retrieve; to optimize REST service performance, these properties are not included in the default query, and must be explicitly requested.

(Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx)

**E.g.**

var Ownurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(' Divisions’)/items?$select="**ColumnName**"&$filter=Title eq 'test1'";

In Your Code :

```
$.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MediaAlbum')/items?$select="Page Image"&$filter=IsActive%20eq%201&$expand=ContentType&,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      });
```

Comment: 400 (Bad Request)